# JTable JQuery Not showing records

Tags: mysql, jquery-jtable

I am using JTable(JQuery) for displaying certain records from database, (database is MySQL)
I am also inserting data using createAction of JTable. I have 3 field which displays date in JTable. The problem that i am facing is when add Type: 'date' for the field which displays date, jtable stops displaying records from database. but when i remove type: 'data' in field it again starts displaying data using listAction. I am not getting why this is happening?
I want create form to show datepicker and also want dates to get displayed in listAction.

Note: I am using yyyy-mm-dd format for date. the following code list record from database when **type: 'date'** is removed from **dateApplied, startDate and endDate** fields. but when type: 'date' is present in the code in these field it fails to display records.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@ page import="daobject.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link href="../css/metro/red/jtable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../js/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.jtable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/calenderStyle.css" type="text/css">

<title>Leave Applications</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#StudentLeaveTableContainer').jtable({
            title: 'Leave Applications',
            actions: {
                    listAction: '/Final_Notebook/StudentLeaveCancelController?action=list',
                    createAction: '/Final_Notebook/StudentLeaveCancelController?action=create', 
                    deleteAction:   '/Final_Notebook/StudentLeaveCancelController?action=delete'          
            },

            fields: {
                To:{
                    title:'Application To',
                    create: true,
                    options: '/Final_Notebook/StudentLeaveCancelController?options=ApplicationTo',
                    list: false
                    },

                leaveId:{
                     key: true,
                     create: false,
                     edit: true,         
                     sorting: false,
                     list: false
                },
                name: {
                    title:'Name',
                    list: true,
                    create:false,
                },
                rollNo: {
                    title: 'Roll No',
                    width: '20%',
                    list: true,
                    edit:true,
                    create: false
                },
                leaveType: {
                    title: 'Type',
                    width: '20%',
                    options:{'personal':'personal','medical':'medical','other':'other'},
                    edit:false,
                    create: true,
                    list: true
                },
                leaveReason: {
                    title: 'Reason',
                    width: '30%',
                    type: 'textarea',
                    edit: false,
                    list: true,
                    create: true
                },
                dateApplied: {
                    title: 'Applied On',
                    width: '30%',
                    list: true,
                    create: true,
                    edit: true,
                    type: 'date',
                    displayFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                },
                startDate: {
                    title: 'From Date',
                    width: '30%',
                    list: true,
                    create: true,
                    edit: true,
                    type: 'date',
                    displayFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                },
                endDate: {
                    title: 'To Date',
                    width: '30%',
                    list: true,
                    create: true,
                    edit: true,
                    type: 'date',
                    displayFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                },
                days: {
                    title: 'Total Days',
                    width: '20%',
                    edit: false,
                    create: true,
                    list: true
                },
                status: {
                    title: 'Status',
                    width: '20%',
                    list: true,
                    edit: false,
                    create: false,
                    options: {'0':'pending', '1':'Apprtoved', '2':'Rejected'}
                }
            }
        });
        $('#StudentLeaveTableContainer').jtable('load');
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div style="width:70%;margin-right:20%;margin-left:20%;text-align:center;">
<h1>Leave Applications</h1>
<div id="StudentLeaveTableContainer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a little heads up, you don't need to specified list: true, create: true and edit: true as they're true by default.

http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference/FieldOptions

Comment: Also, can you show us the json from your listAction?

Answer (score 0):

```
to display records try following:
   dateApplied: {
                title: 'Applied On',
                width: '30%',
                list: true,
                create: true,
                edit: true,
                type: 'date',
                displayFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
               display: function (data) {
                        return data.record.<your-field-name>;
                    },
            },
```